# python - regex putting repeating patterns in a single group

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a string in regex and am 99% there.

my test string is

```
 1
  1234 1111 5555 88945
    172.255.255.255 from 172.255.255.255 (1.1.1.1)
      Origin IGP, localpref 300, valid, external, best
      rx pathid: 0, tx pathid: 0x0
```

my current regex pattern is:

```
(?P<as_path>(\d{4,10}\s){1,20})\s+(?P<peer_addr>\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}).*\((?P<peer_rid>\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3})\)\s+.*localpref\s(?P<local_pref>\d+),\s(?P<attribs>\S+,\s{0,4})
```

im using regex101 to test and have a link to the test here https://regex101.com/r/iGM8ye/1

So currently i have a group2 I don't want this group, could someone tell me why im getting this group and how to remove it?

and the second is, in the attributes I want to match the words, "valid, external, best" currently my pattern only matches "valid," I thought adding the repeat of within the group would of matched all three of those but it hasn't.

How would I achieve matching the repeat of "string, string, string," (string comma space) into one group?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Desired output

```
as_path : 1234 1111 5555 88945
peer_addr : 172.255.255.255
peer_rid : 1.1.1.1
local_pref : 300
attribs : valid, external, best
```

attiribs may also just be valid, external, or just external, or another entry in the format (stringcommaspace)

Comment: Could you include your entire expected/desired output? It's slightly unclear from the question.

Comment: I've done that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See regex in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/iGM8ye/4).

```
(?P<as_path>(?:\d{4,10}\s){1,20})\s+(?P<peer_addr>\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{0,3}){3}).*\((?P<peer_rid>\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{0,3}){3})\)\s+.*localpref\s(?P<local_pref>\d+),\s+(?P<attribs>\S+(?:,\s+\S+){2})
```

1. You were getting group 2 because your `as_path` group contained a group. I changed that to a non-capturing group.
2. I changed `attribs` to `\S+(?:,\s+\S+){2}`

   - This will match any non-space character one or more times `\S+`, followed by the following exactly twice:

     - `,\s+\S+` the comma character, followed by the space character one or more times, followed by any non-space character one or more times
3. I changed `peer_addr` and `peer_rid` to `\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{0,3}){3}` instead of `\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}`. This is a preference, but shortens the expression.

Without that last modification, you can use the following regex (it performs slightly better anyway (as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/iGM8ye/6)):

```
(?P<as_path>(?:\d{4,10}\s){1,20})\s+(?P<peer_addr>\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}).*\((?P<peer_rid>\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3})\)\s+.*localpref\s(?P<local_pref>\d+),\s+(?P<attribs>\S+(?:,\s+\S+){2})
```

---

You can also improve the performance by using more specific tokens as the following suggests (notice I also added the `x` modifier to make it more legible) and as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/iGM8ye/7):

```
(?P<as_path>\d{4,10}(?:\s\d{4,10}){0,19})\s+
(?P<peer_addr>\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3})[^)]*
\((?P<peer_rid>\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3})\)\s+
.*localpref\s(?P<local_pref>\d+),\s+
(?P<attribs>\w+(?:,\s+\w+){2})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Regex: `(?P<as_path>(?:\d{4,10}\s){1,20})\s+(?P<peer_addr>\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}).*\((?P<peer_rid>\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3})\)\s+.*localpref\s(?P<local_pref>\d+),\s(?P<attribs>[\S]+,(?: [\S]+,?)*){0,4}`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iGM8ye/5)

Regex in the question had a capturing group (Group 2) for `(\d{4,10}\s)`. it is changed to a non capturing group now `(?:\d{4,10}\s)`

Answer (score 1):

You get that separate group because your are repeating a capturing group were the last iteration will be the capturing group, in this case `88945` You could make it non capturing instead `(?:`

For the second part you could use an alternation to exactly match one of the options `(?:valid|external|best)`

Your pattern might look like:

```
(?P<as_path>(?:\d{4,10}\s){1,20})\s+(?P<peer_addr>\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}).*\((?P<peer_rid>\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3}\.\d{0,3})\)\s+.*localpref\s(?P<local_pref>\d+),\s(?P<attribs>(?:valid|external|best)(?:,\s{0,4}(?:valid|external|best))+)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/1jO2gG/1)